# elements inside of ul not working in IE

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, html-lists

I have a UL that doesn't Work in IE, but Works fine in chrome, safari and firefox.

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="default_header">
        WebAppName
        <asp:Label ID="LabelUserId" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div id="lookup_header" style="display:none" class="buttonHeader">
        <a id="lookup_cancel" class="cancelButton button blue" href="javascript:PrismeLookup.cancelLookup();">Cancel</a>
        <asp:Label ID="lookup_selected_value" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        <a id="lookup_set" class="setButton button blue" href="javascript:PrismeLookup.setLookup();">Ok</a>

        <ul class='lookup' id='lookup_search'>
            <li>
                <button tabindex='2' onclick='PrismeLookup.search(); return false;'>Search</button>
                <span>
                    <input id='lookup_searchField' tabindex='1' type='text' value='' />
                </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

If i'm tabbing, I can get to the button and input element, but I can't click with my mouse on those elements.

It seems like the button and input element is behind some other element, making them not able to be clicked on.

The CSS for the header:

```
#header
{
    text-align: center;
    color:#FFF;

    height: 45px;               
    position:fixed;
    z-index:5;
    top:0px;
    width:100%;

    top:0; left:0;
    padding:0;

    background-color:#2785c7; /* Old browsers */    
    background:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #206493, #2375ae, #2785c7 85%); /* FF3.6+ */    
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #206493, #2375ae, #2785c7 85%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #206493, #2375ae, #2785c7 85%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #206493, #2375ae, #2785c7 85%); /* IE10+ */
    background:         linear-gradient(top, #206493, #2375ae, #2785c7 85%); /* W3C */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#206493), to(#2375ae), color-stop(85%, #2785c7)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#206493', endColorstr='#2785c7',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

Here is a image of the site:
[image]

It seems like IE does something with the header. When I changes the height from 45px to 90px, it Works, but that will screw up the other pages.

Here is the head element:

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
    <!--<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"/>-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, width=device-width, height=device-height"/>
    <!--<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densityDpi=device-dpi, maximum-scale=1.0"/>-->
    <!--<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>-->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black"/>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"/>    
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/logo.png"/>
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="images/startup.png"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" />

    <title>WebAppName</title>

    <link href="css/style.css?prisme=#VERSION" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="css/divScroll.css?prisme=#VERSION" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js?prisme=#VERSION" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/divScroll.js?prisme=#VERSION" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/javascript.js?prisme=#VERSION" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

**Solution**
Added this in a JavaScript file when showing the page:

```
$('#header').height('90px');
```

and this when hiding the page:

```
$('#header').height('45px');
```

This will be the solution for now.

Comment: Share the css and which version of IE are you using?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net is better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `overflow:auto` or set a specific height more than your current div height `45px` to some more number.

Your current div height prevent your `ul` part (textbox and button) to display on page in IE.

**OR**
 you can remove your `ul` element from `<div id="header">` or add into another div outside of main header div.
 For example :

```
<div style="width: 100%;position: relative;top: 45px;text-align: center;">
<ul class='lookup' id='lookup_search' style="list-style: none;">
  <li>
    <button tabindex='2' onclick='PrismeLookup.search(); return false;'>Search</button>
     <span>
        <input id='lookup_searchField' tabindex='1' type='text' value='' />
     </span>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I think that I've to go for the solution of changing the height of the div header element and resize it back again when showing and hiding the page. Thx for the help :)